The probability of getting a five spade hand given 4 spades vs given at least 4 spades
Edit: Placed the question here:

find the probability of an all spade hand given that there are 4 spades in the hand
find the probability of an all spade hand given there are at least 4 spades in the hand.

For a five card hand, using the conditional probability formula, I worked out the probability of an all spade hand given 4 spades as:
($\frac{13}{52}$ * $\frac{12}{51}$ * $\frac{11}{50}$ * $\frac{10}{49}$ * $\frac{9}{48}$)/
(${5 \choose 4}$*$\frac{13}{52}$ * $\frac{12}{51}$ * $\frac{11}{50}$ * $\frac{10}{49}$ * $\frac{39}{48}$)
which is $\frac{3}{65}$, roughly around 0.046
For the probability of an all spade hand given at least 4 spades, I found this was:
($\frac{13}{52}$ * $\frac{12}{51}$ * $\frac{11}{50}$ * $\frac{10}{49}$ * $\frac{9}{48}$)/
(${5 \choose 4}$*$\frac{13}{52}$ * $\frac{12}{51}$ * $\frac{11}{50}$ * $\frac{10}{49}$ * $\frac{39}{48}$ + $\frac{13}{52}$ * $\frac{12}{51}$ * $\frac{11}{50}$ * $\frac{10}{49}$ * $\frac{9}{48}$)
which is $\frac{3}{68}$, roughly around 0.044
Are my calculations correct? Logically, I thought the probability of the latter case (a 5 spade hand given at least 4 spades) should be higher than the former case (a 5 spade hand given 4 spades). Is this not the case?
Thank you

You'll have to be a bit more clear. To my mind, $P(\text{$5$ spades} \mid \text{exactly $4$ spades}) = 0$, as once you've conditioned on there being exactly $4$ spades, the probability of there being $5$ spades is zero.

Can you reproduce the $\mathtt{exact}$ wording of the problem ?

There were two questions: find the probability of an all spade hand given that there are 4 spades in the hand and find the probability of an all spade hand given there are at least 4 spades in the hand.

Consider for starters that the number of 5-card hands containing 5 spades wouldn’t change if all of, say, the clubs had been removed from the deck. Or if instead a fifth suit of, say, stars had been added to the deck. It’s going to be $13 \choose 5$.

This question is busted. Rita, please address @BrianTung's objection! I'm shooting in the dark here, but perhaps the first question is asking for the probability of five Spades given that the first four cards dealt are all Spades?

[1] On careful reading, I see that the condition "that there are $4$ spades in the hand" is actually the same condition as for [2], as explained below.
$4$ spadees in the  hand leaves open the possibility of $5$ spades in hand
Let event A = P[exactly 4 spades in hand (plus one other)],
event B = P[exactly 5 spades in hand],
so so the reduced sample space is [P(A) + P(B)]
and we want $\dfrac{P(5\;spades\;in\; hand)}{P(A)+P(B)}$
and the answer will be the same as given for [2]
[2] Your answer is correct, but you could consider doing the simpler
$\Large\frac{\binom{13}5}{\binom{13}5 + \binom{13}4\binom{39}1} = \frac3{68} \approx \small 0.0441$
The direct multiplication of probabilities is better only if (a) a particular order is wanted (b) the multiplicative chain is not too long.

For [1]: why is the second combination in the denominator  ${48 \choose 1}$? I thought it might be ${39 \choose 1}$ because we are selecting from the 39 non-spades. Thanks for your help

Sorry I think I'm still not quite understanding. If the wording suggests that the 4 cards revealed are spades, does that mean the combinations we are counting are exactly 4 spades + 5 spades? If that is so, is it the same as at least 4 spades?

Yes, I have reviewed the answer for part [1]
